# Allowed REGEX in Custom Standardization and dealing with TensorFlow tf.strings and TextVectorization

Tags: python, regex, tensorflow, tf.keras

I created a function to preprocess input text and pass it as Custom Standrization in TextVectorization. The function mainly handles text using regex, it was adapted from a previous python code I had that worked fine under the traditional `re` package. When using the same regex in TF strings/TextVectorisation, I faced the following problems particularly due to 1) the allowed regex as part of `tf.strings.regex_replace` and 2) output encoding later on.

The first non-working regex is:

```
lcased = tf.strings.regex_replace(lcased, r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1')  # repeated chars
```

Error is:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid pattern: (.)\1{2,}, error: invalid escape sequence: \1 [Op:StaticRegexReplace]
```

The second non-working regex is:

```
lcased = tf.strings.regex_replace(lcased, r"(?:(?![\t\n\r])\s{2,})", ' ') # repeated_whitespaces
```

Error is:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid pattern: (?:(?![\t\n\r])\s{2,}), error: invalid perl operator: (?! [Op:StaticRegexReplace]
```

Finally, when I use the following code to handle emojis

```
emoji_pattern = "(["+ u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"+"])"
lcased = tf.strings.regex_replace(lcased, emoji_pattern, r" \1 ")
```

to process the following sentence:

```
duplicated emojis!
```

I got the following output

```
b'duplicated emojis!  \xf0\x9f\x98\x89  \xf0\x9f\x98\x89  \xf0\x9f\x98\x89'
```

so how could I fix the encoding and regex problem here?

Full code:

```
def preprocess(input_data):
    lcased = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
    emoji_pattern = "(["+ u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"+"])"
    lcased = tf.strings.regex_replace(lcased, emoji_pattern, r" \1 ") 
    lcased = tf.strings.regex_replace(lcased, r'(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)', r' <hashtag> \1 <hashtag> ')
    lcased = tf.strings.regex_replace(lcased, r"(?:(?![\t\n\r])\s{2,})", ' ')  # repeated_whitespaces 
    lcased = tf.strings.regex_replace(lcased, r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1')  # repeated chars 
    return lcased

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(preprocess(tf.constant(["duplicated emojis!  ",
                  "soooo muccch ...", "many      spaces     here!!!"]
```

Comment: I also have this problem